# How to use SUMIF or any sql query to aggregate the result or results of survey data?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have here a query used in a dashboard to sort survey responses. What I want is for my query to add the result of the  ff ie.

```
'Male - In Love' + 'Female - In Love'; 
'Male - Like' + 'Female - Like'; 
'Male - Facepalm' + 'Female - Facepalm'; 
'Male - Crying' + 'Female - Crying';
```

Here is the query I used to sort individual response:

Btw I'm using laravel 5.4 and mysql

```
public function getDataTwo(Request $request){
    $data = DB::connection('mysql')->select(DB::raw("SELECT 
        DATE(`created_at`) as 'DATE',
        SUM(IF(`responses`=1,1,0)) as 'Male - In Love',
        SUM(IF(`responses`=2,1,0)) as 'Male - Like',
        SUM(IF(`responses`=3,1,0)) as 'Male - Facepalm',
        SUM(IF(`responses`=4,1,0)) as 'Male - Crying',
        SUM(IF(`responses`=5,1,0)) as 'Female - In Love',
        SUM(IF(`responses`=6,1,0)) as 'Female - Like',
        SUM(IF(`responses`=7,1,0)) as 'Female - Facepalm',
        SUM(IF(`responses`=8,1,0)) as 'Female - Crying'
        FROM `answers` 
        WHERE DATE(`created_at`) BETWEEN DATE('$request->startDate') AND
        DATE('$request->endDate')                             
        AND TIME(`created_at`) BETWEEN TIME('$request->startDate') AND 
        TIME('$request->endDate')
        -- AND driverid = ('*')
        -- AND busid = ('*')
        -- AND routeid = ('*')
        -- AND questionid = ('*') 
        GROUP BY DATE(`created_at`)"
    )); //Array and Result nito
    $tempArr = array();
    if(count($data)==0){return $data;}
    $xcnt=0;
    foreach ($data[0] as $key => $value) {
        if($key=='DATE'){continue;}
        $tempArr[$xcnt]=array("name"=>$key,"y"=>(int)$value);
        $xcnt++;
    }
    $data = json_encode($tempArr);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: What's actually happening? What are you expecting to happen? Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using MySQL, so your query can more easily be written using this shortcut:

```
SELECT DATE(created_at) as DATE,
       SUM(responses = 1) as `Male - In Love`,
       SUM(responses = 2) as `Male - Like`,
       SUM(responses = 3) as `Male - Facepalm`,
       SUM(responses = 4) as `Male - Crying`,
       SUM(responses = 5) as `Female - In Love`,
       SUM(responses = 6) as `Female - Like`,
       SUM(responses = 7) as `Female - Facepalm`,
       SUM(responses = 8) as `Female - Crying`
FROM answers 
. . .
```

Then, you can easily add more columns as:

```
SELECT DATE(created_at) as DATE,
       SUM(responses = 1) as `Male - In Love`,
       SUM(responses = 2) as `Male - Like`,
       SUM(responses = 3) as `Male - Facepalm`,
       SUM(responses = 4) as `Male - Crying`,
       SUM(responses = 5) as `Female - In Love`,
       SUM(responses = 6) as `Female - Like`,
       SUM(responses = 7) as `Female - Facepalm`,
       SUM(responses = 8) as `Female - Crying`,
       SUM(responses IN (1, 5)) as `Males + Females - In Love`),
       . . . 
FROM answers 
. . .
```

Notes:

- `IF()` is already non-standard SQL.  You might as well use MySQL's more convenient "treat booleans as numbers" extension.
- Only use single quotes for string and date constants.  Don't use them for column aliases.